# Returning a list element using positions

Tags: list, haskell, position

I have recently taken upon myself to learn Haskell and, in one of the first lessons, I have been told to learn how to manipulate lists first. I understand how to pick a list element from it's position like this

```
    myList = [7, 3, 6, 15, 8]
    myList !! 3
```

Now, I would want to know if it's possible to pick a position starting from the last element of the list, just like what I have been doing in Python using this

```
    pythonlist = [7, 3, 6, 15, 8]
    pythonlist[-2]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, if you find yourself accesing lists by index (which you shouldn't often do anyway, it's inefficient and ugly: prefer functional tools such as folds, `map`, and the monad instance) then you should better switch to some array data type, e.g. [`Vector`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.10.9.1/docs/Data-Vector.html).

But sure enough it's *possible* to access lists by index, also from the back:

```
(!!<) :: [a] -> Int -> a
l !!< i = l !! i'
 where i' = length l - i - 1
```

I hope it's obvious enough how this works. It's even more inefficient than ordinary access because `length` traverses the entire list, but there you are.

Comment: Is this also correct (!!<) :: [a] -> Int -> a
l !!< i = (reverse l) !! i

Comment: Yes, perhaps even a bit nicer.

Comment: I will just add it for the sake of diversity :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do :

```
(!!<) :: [a] -> Int -> a 
l !!< i = (reverse l) !! i
```

But it means you cannot use negative numbers, only a positive index, but it will look from the end of the list.

Or if you really wanna use negatives:

```
(!!<) :: [a] -> Int -> a
l !!< i = if i < 0 then l !! (length l + i) else l !! i
```

Answer (score 0):

In certain cases, yes. You can simply redefine `(!!)` to:

```
xs !! i | i >= 0 = xs Data.List.!! i
        | i < 0 = let n = length xs
                  in xs Data.List.!! (n+i)
```

However, this isn't really a great idea in Haskell due to *laziness*. The solution above works on *finite* lists, which is what you are talking about in Python. Consider what happens on an infinite list, however: `[1..] !! (-2)`. We first evaluate `length [1..]`, which never terminates! The problem is that you can't index from the end of an infinite list.

Comment: To make this at least somewhat consistent, I'd rather define a new operator e.g. ``xs !!! i = xs !! (i `mod` length list)``, to allow negative indices as a special case of "safe indexing by wrap-around". But actually I'd prefer not to have that possibility at all, it's IMO more confusing than helpful.